Hybrid WordPress Theme: page.php Not Recognized When theme.json is Present
I am working on a hybrid WordPress theme that includes both page.php and theme.json. My goal is to create a custom page template, but I am encountering a problem where WordPress indicates that my page template is empty when theme.json is present.
Here's the issue:
When theme.json is present in my theme directory, WordPress does not recognize my page.php template, and I receive an error message saying that the page template is empty.
When I remove theme.json from the theme directory, WordPress detects page.php correctly, and my custom page template works as expected.
//page.php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

//theme.json
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
  "version": 3,
  "settings": {
    "color": {
      "text": true,
      "background": true,
      "custom": true,
      "customDuotone": true,
      "customGradient": true,
      "defaultGradients": false,
      "defaultPalette": false,
      "defaultDuotone": false,
      "palette": [
        {
          "name": "Blue",
          "slug": "blue",
          "color": "#3B82F6"
        },
        {
          "name": "Indigo",
          "slug": "indigo",
          "color": "#6366F1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Purple",
          "slug": "purple",
          "color": "#8B5CF6"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pink",
          "slug": "pink",
          "color": "#EC4899"
        },
        {
          "name": "Red",
          "slug": "red",
          "color": "#EF4444"
        },
        {
          "name": "Yellow",
          "slug": "yellow",
          "color": "#F59E0B"
        },
        {
          "name": "Green",
          "slug": "green",
          "color": "#10B981"
        },
        {
          "name": "Gray",
          "slug": "gray",
          "color": "#6B7280"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cool Gray",
          "slug": "cool-gray",
          "color": "#9CA3AF"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


